# Passing inputField value from apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce

EDIT:
Create products:

```
List<wrapperClass> WrapperClassList = new List<wrapperClass>();
public List<wrapperClass> getProducts() 
{
    List<Product2> products = new List<Product2>();

    for(product2 p : [select id,name,... from product2]) {
       Product2 pro = (Product2)p;
       wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass(pro);            
       WrapperClassList.add(wc);
    }
    return WrapperClassList;
}
```

Save button:

```
public PageReference save() 
{   
       try {
           system.debug(WrapperClassList);     
       } 
        catch(Exception e){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, e.getMessage()));
            return null;
           }
   return null;
}
```

END:

I've PageBlockTable that allows users to enter multiple values at one time. I'm not sure how to pass the entered value when the user click on save button. In other words how can I pass the Input field value from Visualforce page to apex controller class.

Wrapper class:

```
public wrapperClass 
{    
  public Product2 product {get;set;}
  public Asset_Line_Item__c ali {get;set;}

  public wrapperClass(Product2 p){
      product = p;
      ali = New Asset_Line_Item__c();
  }
}
```

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="a">                     
          <apex:column headerValue="quantity" >                            
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.ali.qty}" required="true" />                    
          </apex:column>
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Apex Code:

this is how i'm updating the wrapperClass

```
for(product2 p : [select id,name,... from product2]) {
   Product2 pro = (Product2)p;
   wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass(pro);            
   WrapperClassList.add(wc);
}
```

Comment: You have to write a save method that iterates over the wrapper to grab the values and update as needed. What are you still using inputtext and not input field?

Comment: sorry copy and paste, i am using inputField, will update the post

Comment: i would use `WrapperClassList` in the controller?

Comment: You already have it, it is called `products`. So your save method would iterate of it and grab the applicable values

Comment: its not holding the latest data in the `products` wrapperclass and i have system.debug(products) i see the quantity null, even though i have entered value and as soon as i hit the save button page refresh and clear the values from inputfield

Comment: We will need more code, specifically around how you create products and your save method. As well as your action on the page

Comment: Updated my question, i have added how i'm creating the wrapperclass for products and for the save i do not have much except that system.debug to see what i am getting the values from pageblocktable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45420/discussion-between-eric-and-nick-kahn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by modifying your code as follows:

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

**Class**

```
    public class myExample {

public List<wrapperClass> products{
    get {
        if(products == null){
            products = new List< wrapperClass >();

            for(product2 p : [select id,name from product2 limit 4]) {
                products.add(New wrapperClass(p));
            }
        }
        return products;
    }
    set;
}


    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            for (wrapperClass w : products) {
                system.debug('The Quantity is: ' + w.ali.Quantity);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, e.getMessage()));
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class wrapperClass {
        public Product2 product { get; set; }
        public opportunitylineitem ali { get; set; }

        public wrapperClass(Product2 p) {
            product = p;
            ali = New opportunitylineitem();
        }
    }



    }
```

**VFP**

```
<apex:form id="editForm">

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!products}" var="a">
            <apex:column headerValue="quantity">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.ali.Quantity}" required="true"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:commandbutton value="save me" action="{!save}" rerender=""/>

</apex:form>
```

Comment: let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Eric, I have implement your code and test it and as soon as i click the save button the pageblockTable disappears

Comment: One thing at a time. Does the debug output the values at you expect? The code I have would not cause the PBT to disappear

Comment: nope, its empty

Comment: @NickKahn - See updated code. I used OLI by you can replace with your custom object

Comment: 1+ thanks , i was missing `products = tmp;`  appreciate your help.

Comment: I updated it to remove the tmp part and directly assign to products